# How does IBM Connections' ActivityStreams outputs newsData's content?

Tags: connection, ibm-sbt

The newsItem.newsData object contains several content-related getters like 'getActivitySummary()', 'getContent()' (probably some other). They can return null/undefined, however ActivityStreams always outputs correctly (more often the summary goes to the page). What is the order/algorithm of outputting the content?

Comment: I'm sure they map directly to the underlying ActivityStreams standard. Summary/Content and other most likely map to posted content.  if the summary or content field is not present, I'm sure it'd return a null.          you can always do a typeof to check if the element is null before using it.

Comment: So looks like summary is used first, then content if summary is null/undefined. I guess both cannot be null/undefined, because Connections kind of disallow empty posts.

Comment: which would make sense, use the typeof to double check the null.